# Ember - Sideloading data within RESTAPISerializer

Tags: rest, ember.js, serialization

I am trying to sideload data with RESTAPISerializer, but there seems to be some problem.

The goal is to store articles with tags. The articles appear in the store just fine, and I can look at them with Ember inspector. But I can't seem to figure out how to store the tags, they never show up in the inspector.

I created a model called blog-tag to store the tags. They come in a specific format, which I can't change, and it looks like this:

```
tid:term
```

... and I am getting an array of them with each article.

The article model includes a hasMany relationship with blog-tags. I am trying to pass them in through the serializer, and have been using various formats (JSON, javascript arrays, etc.) I wrote a custom serializer for blog tags as well, but it doesn't seem to do much.

Can someone explain what I am missing?

The article model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  blogTags: hasMany('blog-tag', { async: true })
});
```

The blog-tag model:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
  tid: attr('number'),
  term: attr('string'),
});
```

The article serializer:

```
import RESTAPISerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';

export default RESTAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse: function(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {

    var normalizedPayload = {articles: []};

    payload.forEach(function(item) {

      var tags = item.tags.split("|"), blogTags = [];

      // storing blog tags in an array, have also done it as a
      // JSON structure
      var blogTags = tags.map((tag) => {
        var item = tag.split(":"),
        vals = {};
        vals.tid = item[0];
        vals.term = item[1];
        return vals;
      });

      var article = {
        id: item.nid,
        title: item.title,
        blogTags: blogTags,
      };

      normalizedPayload.articles.push(article);

    });
    return this._super(store, primaryModelClass, normalizedPayload, id, requestType);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Answering the question for the benefit of anyone else running into the same issue.

What I was trying to do is embed the tags from the articles serializer. This mean I needed to use the EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html

It was actually pretty simple to do this. Made the following changes to the serializer described above, the code worked as-is with these additions.

```
// app/serializers/articles.js
import RESTSerializer from 'ember-data/serializers/rest';
import EmbeddedRecordsMixin from 'ember-data/serializers/embedded-records-mixin';
export default RESTSerializer.extend(EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

  attrs: {
    blogTags: { embedded: 'always' }
  }

});
```